# Facing problem during codeblocks uninstall Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 12.04

I tried to install codeblocks IDE which actually got terminated in the middle by throwing some problem after that I am not able to install any other software like flash player and the system is not able to uninstall it either, plz refer the messsage below
Reading state information... Done

```
libwxgtk2.8-0 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libgamin0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libhunspell-1.2-0 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 12.11-1) but 12.11-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 12.11-1) but 12.11-3 is to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0 : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 12.11-3) but 12.11-1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: codeblocks-contrib (= 12.11-3) but 12.11-1 is to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0-dev : Depends: libwxsmithlib-dev (= 12.11-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error said try the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After that you can install any softwares.

Comment: I tried using that command but nothing positive till now

Comment: what was the error did you got after trying `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: It runs an upgrade check and remove some folders and then asks me that some space will be made after the operaiton when I press Y i get this error Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_12.11-3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: try these commands `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_12.11-3_i386.deb` then `sudo apt-get clean` then `sudo apt-get -f install`